# Hamiltonian system: match transformations and constants of motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism

I have a problem about the interpretation of an exercise.

Given the following Hamiltonian

$$H=\frac{\mathbf{p_0}^2}{2m}+\frac{\mathbf{p_1}^2}{2m}+\frac{\mathbf{p_2}^2}{2m}-2V(\mathbf{r_1}- \mathbf{r_0})+V(\mathbf{r_2}-\mathbf{r_1})$$

where $$V(\mathbf x)=\frac {e^2}{|\mathbf x|}.$$

I have to

> enumerate all the continue transformation such as the form of H remains unchanged and match to each one a costant of motion.

I have thought that the form of H remains unchanged for translation and rotation, but I don't know how I can match a constant of motion. Is "constant of motion" linked to "generating function of the transformation"?

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66717/2451 and links therein.