# Are all aperiodic systems chaotic?

Tags: chaos-theory, complex-systems

So I understand that a chaotic system is a deterministic system, which produces aperiodic long-term behaviour and is hyper-sensitive to initial conditions.

So are all aperiodic systems chaotic? Are there counter-examples?

Comment: Depending upon what exactly you mean by 'aperiodic' there might be trivial examples e.g. a damped harmonic oscillator's motion is a decaying spiral in phase space which isn't strictly periodic.

Comment: @jacob1729  or it decays to a stable infinite period :-)

Comment: What about translation on the plane?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No.

A system might be, for instance, stochastic, random - which is certainly not an example of *deterministic* chaos, but is aperiodic.

You can also have [quasiperiodic behavior](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Quasiperiodicity), where the system comes *close* (but not exactly) to previous states, for which the simplest example is the [circle map](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircleMap.html): $x \mapsto a+x$, where $a$ is irrational and $x$ is angle-like (e.g., $x\mapsto x\in[0,1)$). This dynamics is aperiodic, but not sensitive to initial conditions.

Also a [damped harmonic oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator#Damped_harmonic_oscillator) doesn't come back to exactly the same state, since energy is being lost and, thus, is strictly not periodic (nor sensitive to initial conditions).

These deterministic aperiodic but non-chaotic behaviors are often called *regular*, as in the classic book [Regular and Chaotic Dynamics](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9780387977454) by Lichtenberg and Lieberman.

A related question is [Conditions for periodic motions in classical mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/373872/75633).

Comment: Even a particle with constant non-null speed is moving aperiodically and non-chaotically.

Comment: I think another simple example would be a system with two independent oscillators which do not interact in any way, but where the ratio between the two periods is an irrational number.

Comment: @supercat Yes, that would be quasiperiodic. Considering that the energies of both oscillators are independently conserved, I wonder if there is a correspondence to the circle map...